# Bake Console on MacOSX

Tags: macos, bash, cakephp

I am trying to install the Baking Console on MacOSX. (first time user of MAC)

I opened my Terminal and hit nano `.profile` then added the following lines. I am using Mamp for my Stack.

```
export PATH="/Application/Mamp/htdocs/mink7/lib/Cake/Console:$PATH"
export PATH="/Applications/bin/php5/bin/:$PATH"
```

Now i navigated to the `/Application/Mamp/htdocs/mink7/app`
and when i hit `cake` i get the following error

```
-bash: cake: command not found
```

Answer (score 2):

### Don't put cake in `PATH`

It's not necessary and can cause complications. Such as [coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/)'s cli also being named cake (and that *is* expected to be in the path).

The recommended way to use the cli is to execute the [app-specific](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.5.1/app/Console/cake) cli like so:

```
$ cd /Application/Mamp/htdocs/mink7/app
$ Console/cake
Welcome to CakePHP v2.5.1 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : app
Path: /Application/Mamp/htdocs/mink7/app
---------------------------------------------------------------
Current Paths:
...
```

Comment: this doesnt need to me change path for every app. is that the reason?

Comment: @HarshaMV it's one reason, the main reason is that it-just-works®. For example I haven't had cake in my path for at least 3 years and I develop almost-exclusively with CakePHP.